# Accessing Key Value Pair in JSON data results

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable

I haven't needed to access JSON data so I'm a bit stumped. I've validated the data using a JSON formatter and it is valid so I know that is good.

All I'm trying to do is retrieve the data and populate a select box (specifically x-editable).

In there example, they provide:

```
$('#id').editable({
    source: [
        {value: 1, text: 'Male'},
        {value: 2, text: 'Female'}
    ]
});
```

Yes, I could throw the 50 states in there but I'd like to use this same approach for other select boxes I plan on implementing.

Here is the datafeed I'm currently getting back from my JSON call:

```
{
"data": [{
    "stateID": 1,
    "stateAbbr": "AL",
    "state": "Alabama"
}, {
    "stateID": 2,
    "stateAbbr": "AK",
    "state": "Alaska"
}, {
    "stateID": 3,
    "stateAbbr": "AZ",
    "state": "Arizona"
}, {
    "stateID": 51,
    "stateAbbr": "WY",
    "state": "Wyoming"
}]}
```

My function snippet that I'm working with is:

```
$.getJSON("test.html?format=json",function(data){
    statesArr = statesArr.concat(data);
});
```

Ideally, I'd like to make the statesArr look like this:

```
source: [
        {value: 1, text: 'Alabama'},
        {value: 2, text: 'Alaska'},
        ...
        {value:50, text: 'Wyoming'}
    ]
```

But I'm at a loss on what to do from here. The format of the data feed, `{"data` is throwing me off. I'm used to getting data pretty much like X-Editable is looking for.

Comment: statesArr = statesArr.concat(data); should be statesArr = statesArr.concat(JSON.parse(data)); Otherwise it is just a string being concatted to your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming here that `resp` is the response. And resp has `data` property. If I have misunderstood you, please tell me so.

```
var statesArr;
$.getJSON('test.html?format=json', function(resp){
    statesArr = resp.data.map(function(state){
        return {
            value: state.stateID,
            text: state.state
        }
    });
});

/* somewhere else later; make sure that statesArr is set */
$('#id').editable({
    source: statesArr
});
```

Comment: @HPWD A small edit, I am a bit confused with {data:data}

Comment: the JSON result I'm showing is the actual data coming back, just took out 47 states worth of data to keep dataset smaller. I usually use `data` and my response variable so I apologize if that is causing confusion since the JSON data also has `data` in it, too.

Comment: @HPWD then the new version should do it. For clarity I renamed the whole response data to `resp`, so that it's clear that it has a property `data` on it.

Comment: Getting a quick bite to eat and I’ll try the update. I wasn’t expecting a response so quickly. :)

Comment: @HPWD what if instead of `data.map` you do `resp.map`? If it fails, then could you post output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(resp))`?

Comment: I'm using resp.map. I think there may be some more confusion. Your solution ties the respon to id of id (#id) but I need this to be a global variable since it'll be used in multiple places.

Comment: console output: `resp is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:28`

Comment: My desire is to have the ajax retrieve the data, assign the resulting data (response) so that the data is ready long before the user even has a chance to click on the edit state field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155130/discussion-between-hlfrmn-and-hpwd).

Comment: I had a an error elsewhere in my code - your solution worked once I figured that out. Thank you for taking the time yesterday to help me work through this. I also changed out my "data" to "response" per your suggestion.

Comment: @HPWD you are welcome. I would advise you to just return the data itself from your backend without wrapping it in `data` property.

Comment: I would if I could but the feed is being provided by another department so I have to work with what they are providing. It's the first time I've had to work with a data set formatted like this.